# Call a structure from a single file in every other class

Tags: swift, xcode

I made a single file for a structure that I need to call in other classes but I am trying everything to make it work but it seems I am not going to make this alone and figure it out.

Code for single file:

```
import Foundation

struct CustomLanguage {

func createBundlePath () -> Bundle {
    let selectedLanguage = "en" 
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: selectedLanguage, ofType: "lproj")
    return Bundle(path: path!)!
    }
}
```

other class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class signInViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var welcomeLabelSignIn: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    welcomeLabelSignIn.text = NSLocalizedString("Welcome!", tableName: nil, bundle: "the structure call here" , value: "", comment: "")
}
```

so at the bundle: I Need to call that structure

[the single file for the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3CZC.png)

[I can't call it to localize the labels, buttons... in other classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag1oc.png)

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Done mate :)

Comment: Did you add the `CustomLanguage` file to the correct targets?

Comment: @DávidPásztor what do you mean by correct targets please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
 struct CustomLanguage {

      static func createBundlePath () -> Bundle {
        let selectedLanguage = "en" 
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: selectedLanguage,  ofType: "lproj")
       return Bundle(path: path!)!
     }
}
```

Then;

```
     welcomeLabelSignIn.text = NSLocalizedString("Welcome!", tableName: nil, bundle: CustomLanguage.createBundlePath() , value: "", comment: "")
```